# Why is ember-data not loading my fixtures?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My Ember app is based on a significant amount of common data (think textbook) in addition to arbitrary user data (think bookmarks). I intend to load the common data from fixtures, and to that end I created two data stores, one using ember-data's REST adapter (for user data) and one using the fixtures adapter (for the common data).

However, the fixtures adapter is not loading fixture data. [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjmorse/65eRS/) is a reduction to minimum of what I'm trying to do: it defines an app, a model, fixtures on that model, a store using the fixtures adapter, and then a controller which gets (or tries to get) its content from the store. But it gets... nothing. What am I doing wrong?

```js
Sylvius = Ember.Application.create();

Sylvius.Section = DS.Model.extend({
  // e.g. Surface, Sectional, Pathways, Visual Glossary
  title: DS.attr('string')
});

Sylvius.Section.FIXTURES = [{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Surface Anatomy"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "title": "Sectional Anatomy"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "title": "Pathways"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "title": "Visual Glossary"
}];

Sylvius.fixtureStore = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 4,
  adapter: DS.fixtureAdapter
});

Sylvius.sectionController = Em.ArrayController.create({
    content: Sylvius.fixtureStore.findAll(Sylvius.Section); 
});
```

​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the problem is the `semicolon` in the `Sylvius.sectionController`s' `content` definition. If you delete it, it works, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/Kpdqd/:

```js
...

Sylvius.sectionController = Em.ArrayController.create({
    content: Sylvius.fixtureStore.findAll(Sylvius.Section)
});
```

Comment: That did it (again). With that working I was able to add code back into the fiddle until I found out which parts of my application code were breaking the import in the full app.